# What is Spring DSL equivalent for Spring XML "depends-on" attribute in Grails

Tags: grails

Consider I can write that in `resources.xml`:

```
<bean id="beanOne" class="ExampleBean" depends-on="manager,accountDao"/>
```

I would write it using Spring DSL in `resources.groovy`. How to write `depends-on` directive?

Comment: +1 Appreciate for bringing up this question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
beanOne(ExampleBean) { bean ->
  bean.dependsOn = ['manager', 'accountDao']
}
```

should do what you're after.  Most of the `<bean>` attributes have `bean.XXX` equivalents, including `init-method`, `destroy-method`, `factory-bean`, `factory-method`, `autowire` - just use camel case instead of hyphens (e.g. `bean.initMethod = "..."`).  If that doesn't work then `bean.beanDefinition` will give you a reference to the actual Spring [`BeanDefinition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html) object so you can call its other methods.

Comment: I was totally unaware of this property of `BeanDefinition`. Thanks for clarifying. Should that be set as a string array instead. `['manager', 'accountDao'] as String[]` otherwise it will be treated as a list.

Comment: @dmahapatro possibly, though Groovy may do the conversion for you automatically when it sees that you've passed a `List` to a method that expects a `String[]`, I'm never 100% sure which conversions happen by magic and which don't.

Comment: It complains for me when I write a [simple script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6102172/).

Comment: @dmahapatro it failed for me in a script too, but when I make it a [proper class](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6102184/) and do the property setter assignment the way my answer does, it does the correct conversion.

Comment: works like a charm. Before I've asked this question on SO I've tried this bean.dependsOn = "beanName" - it didn't work, as `setDependsOn()` method require `String[]` as the argument. Thanks.

Comment: What form of `dependsOn` should I use in Grails service to make service dependant on some bean?

Comment: @archer The same way Ian has mentioned although you would be overriding the service bean declaration after specifying it explicitly in resources.

Comment: @archer I would just add a `def accountDao` (or whatever) to the service class. Even if you don't actually use the injected bean for anything the auto wiring mechanism will ensure the right dependency ordering. I would steer clear of trying to override the service bean definition in `resources.groovy` because the services plugin does all sorts of clever stuff for transaction support which you would have to duplicate in your override definition.

Comment: Added `@Autowired accountDao` to MyService class. However, it seems this still does not work, as I'm still getting: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)`

Answer (score 1):

I think better is to use [org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) annotation at least for services created via services plugin, not via `resources.groovy`.